# Как называть классы, при использовании пространства имен?

Tags: php, ооп, namespace

Я создаю проект, в котором будет несколько классов. Каждый класс будет отвечать за работу с определенным типом данных - строками, массивами и т.д.

Я создал класс Strings.php

```
<?php

namespace MyPHPProject;

class Strings
{

function test()
{
echo 'пространство MyPHPProject класс Strings метод test';
}

}
```

Далее я использую его в файле index.php

```
<?php

include_once __DIR__.'/Strings.php';

use MyPHPProject\Strings;

$strings=new Strings();
//$strings=new MyPHPProject\Strings(); // Ещё один вариант использования

$strings->test();
```

Имя Strings распространено и часто встречается. И если будет подключено какое либо другое пространство имен содержащее класс с таким же именем, то возникнет конфликт. Конфликт при создании экземпляра класса, без явного указания пространства имен. Конструкция use становится бесполезна.

Придется вместо use писать не очень красивый вариант в виде MyPHPProject\Strings.

**Как называть классы, при использовании пространства имен?** До пространства имен были префиксы.

Теперь, снова придется вернуться к префиксам в виде MyPHPStrings, но уже чтобы избежать кода в виде MyPHPProject\Strings()?

Answer (score 2):

> Имя Strings распространено и часто встречается. И если будет подключено какое либо другое пространство имен содержащее класс с таким же именем, то возникнет конфликт.

Используем псевдонимы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php
и ноль проблем

```
use My\Full\Classname as Another;

$test = new Another();
```

Comment: это частично решает проблему. Теперь мы не пишем длинную строку вида MyPHPProject\Strings и это плюс. Но теперь мы пишем псевдоним класса  Another(). Но в этом мало смысла т.к. мы сами могли назвать наш класс Another или MyPHPString или даже MyPHP_String. И вот мы вернулись к префиксам, которые были до неймспейсов. Псевдоним неймспейса разрешил конфликт имен классов? Да. Возник бы этот конфликт, если бы мы использовали у наших классов имена с префиксами Петя_КлассПети (как раньше)? Скорее всего нет - так и писали до неймспейсов, но теоретически мог бы т.к. Петь много.

Comment: Ты слишком загоняешься.... Я написал так, как это делают все адекватные разработчики. И даже в доках указано...Если ты искал одобрение своих слов - то ты ошибся. И если ты не искал верный ответ как правильно делать, то мог бы просто делать как задумал и не задавать вопрос. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Также не забудь, что есть рекомендации PSR, которым следуют почти все разработчики. И это сейчас использование пространства имён и адекватное читаемое название класса, которое говорит само за себя..... И ещё, представь, что проект у тебя большой, ты пишешь ядро фреймворка, вложенность большая. А теперь подумай, будет ли удобно всем писать название класса в виде `new myFramework_core_web_templateGenerator_controllers_launcher()`  во всём проекте. Тебя проклянут))